# How to call a method after IBAction code block on Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ibaction

I have created an iPhone board game. It has the ability to choose if user wants to play multi player or single player.

I've used the `UIButton` for the pieces in the board.

I have got one thing that I want to fix: In Single Player mode, I have implemented AI's turn into `UIButton`'s `IBAction`. But, in this case, there's no time there between player1's move and player2's move. **Both gets executed at the same time.**

**I'd like to do this:** Make human's move immediate, and then the computer thinks for his move. I don't want both moves come together and after that computer thinks to the move.

I know that the problem is that because the game reads the entire code block in IBAction and then he shows the result, but i don't know how to fix this.

Any suggestion?

If you need it, I can show the code, but I think (and I hope, too) that, you'll understand what i mean.

Because of the comments who requested it, here's the code..

-(void)buttonClickedSinglePlayer:(id)sender{

```
[self memorizzastatopartitapassato];
[self volumebottoni];
turno = [self whosTurn];
UIButton *bottoneCampoGioco = sender;
UIButton *bottoneIntelligente;

//Checks if it's Human's turn

if (turno == 0) {
    int valoreBottone = [bottoneCampoGioco.currentTitle intValue];
    if(valoreBottone< 10){

        //if controls are ok, it changes value of human's chosen button

        if((bottoneCampoGioco.currentTitleColor != [UIColor greenColor])){
            [UIView transitionWithView:bottoneCampoGioco duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:nil completion:nil];
            [bottoneCampoGioco setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [bottoneCampoGioco setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
            bottoneCampoGioco.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [bottoneCampoGioco.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];                [bottoneCampoGioco setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottonerosso.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [self incrementaTitoloOnClick :bottoneCampoGioco];
        }

        //else alert and loop to first line of the code, until he chooses a valid move
        else {
            [self posizionenonconsentita];
            turno = [self whosTurn];
            goto end;
        }
    }
    else{
        int x =[self mossedisponibilirosse];
        if (x== 1) {

            [self analizzavincitore];
        }

            [self numeroMax];
        turno = [self whosTurn];
        goto end;
    }


    turno = 1;
    [self analizzaBottoni:bottoneCampoGioco];
    [self aggiornapunteggi];
    [self memorizzastatopresente];
```

## pragma mark Single Player's Action

```
    //Azione del giocatore singolo

    //changes turn token's value to allow to AI to play

    turno = [self whosTurn];
    turno = 0;

    ai = [[ArtificialIntelligence alloc]init];

    //send to AI's class the human's pressed button


    [ai setbottonepremuto:bottoneCampoGioco];
    [ai setDimensioneInput:dimensioneInput];

    //send the situation of the board

    [ai setSituazione:arraycampogioco];
    [ai setpunteggiogiocatori:volumerossi giocatoree2:volumeverdi];

    //get back the chosen button from ai's class
    bottoneIntelligente=[ai bottone];
    [mossaEffettuata setText:[self stringaCoordinateDaBottone:bottoneIntelligente]];
    int valoreBottone2 = [bottoneIntelligente.currentTitle intValue];

    //then changes the value of the button chosen from ai's class

    if(valoreBottone2< 10){

        [UIView transitionWithView:bottoneIntelligente duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop animations:nil completion:nil];
        [bottoneIntelligente setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [bottoneIntelligente setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
        bottoneIntelligente.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [bottoneIntelligente.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f)];
        [bottoneIntelligente setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottoneverde.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self incrementaTitoloOnClick :bottoneIntelligente];
        [self analizzaBottoni:bottoneIntelligente];
        [self aggiornapunteggi];

    }

end:

    turno = [self whosTurn];
}
turno = [self whosTurn];
numeromosse ++;
```

}

Comment: Yes, in this version i save (player 1)'s move and then i pass it to another class which calculates (player 2)'s move.

Comment: Inside `IBAction`'s code, it analyzes Human's move and immediately after that it calculates AI's move. The problem is that even if i add a timer between 2 moves, it makes everything together at the end of `IBAction`'s block. In `ViewDidLoad` i called the method which creates the field game, inside that method i add `IBAction` to each button..i don't know how can i call separately ai's method.

Comment: Now, probably it's a time to add some code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to execute the AI section of the code after a delay.  If you can refactor the code into another method, then you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` which would look like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(aiMove) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

This would run the method after 2 seconds.  Or you can use GCD's `dispatch_after` which looks like this (below). Place the code that you want to run after a delay into the block.

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

 // 
 //Your code goes here
 //

 });
```

Comment: i don't need to wait 2 or more seconds, because the calculation of AI's takes about 0.5 seconds. what i need is that Human chooses the move through `IBAction`'s block code, and only when it finishes, it starts calculating AI's move.. i hope to be understandable.. :(

Comment: So you mean you want to wait for a certain block of code to finish executing, and THEN execute the AI? If so, you should probably be separating the two methods, and then using a callback to trigger the second method once the first one completes.  As a hack, you can try `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` - you'll still need to separate the code into another method, and this will block the main thread until the code has executed (the user has made a move).

Comment: that's what i need, i think!! today i'll try using a callback and then i'll write another comment if it's ok or not ;) thank you!!!

Comment: I had to write the moves into 2 different methods, i linked them with `[self performSelector:@selector(aiMove) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];` and it works perfectly!!! thank you very much!!!!